# Skype not get dependency libQtNetwork.so.4

Tags: 14.04, dependencies, skype

When I try to run skype command it gives me error

```
skype: error while loading shared libraries: libQtNetwork.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

located libQtNetwork.so.4 in my system, the result are

```
skype: error while loading shared libraries: libQtNetwork.so.4: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
sandepp@tony:~$ locate libQtNetwork.so.4
/opt/google/earth/free/libQtNetwork.so.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtNetwork.so.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtNetwork.so.4.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtNetwork.so.4.8.6
sandepp@tony:~$ locate skype
/etc/dbus-1/system.d/skype.conf
/usr/bin/skype
/usr/share/skype
/usr/share/applications/skype.desktop
/usr/share/doc/skype
```

What can I do so the skype gets the required dependency
I am using Ubuntu 14.04 64bit trusty-thar

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-network:i386
```

Comment: I already tried it the result showed libqt4-network is already the newest version.
libqt4-network:i386 is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  kde-l10n-engb libfreeimage3 python-colorama python-dateutil python-decorator
  python-distlib python-html5lib python-matplotlib-data python-pyparsing
  python-support python-tz python-wheel
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 451 not upgraded.

Comment: You don't seem to have the `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtNetwork.so.4` 
`/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtNetwork.so.4.8`  `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtNetwork.so.4.8.6` based on the output of `locate`.